# Adding saved places into a shared Google Maps list

Tags: google-maps

A friend has created a Google Maps list so that we can both starting adding to it places of interest for our upcoming holiday. He set that list to "shared", i.e. there's now a private link to it, which I have. Indeed, when logged in with my own Google account, I can see that list and its contents, and "follow" the list.

However, I cannot add anything to it. That is, when I navigate to a place in Google Maps and click Save, all I see are my own lists, and not also the said shared list which I'm following. I'd additionally like to be able to delete existing saved places from the list.

I'm guessing this feature is simply not yet available, otherwise Google would have made it easy to use.

What I wonder, though, is whether any workaround can be thought up to achieve my aims?

Comment: Asking here after my question got booed off [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73510425/adding-saved-places-into-a-shared-google-maps-list).

Comment: There isn't much in the way of GIS content here.

Comment: Which SE site is most appropriate for this question? I thought both the GIS and SO are at least half-relevant places. The Travel SE has hardly any questions on Google Maps at all.

Comment: I think editing map data is on topic, whether it's using cloud (i.e Google Maps, ArcGIS Online, etc.), server or desktop software.

Answer (score 4):

**This does not seem to work on the web app, but it does work on the mobile app.** I just tested this on Android and iOS.

**Open the link on a mobile device with the Google Maps app installed.**
It will open the app and give you the option to join with a "(+ Join)"- button, after clicking that button you are asked to confirm you Google account and whether you want to join as an "Become an editor" or "View only". - go click "Become an editor".
From that point onwards you can see this shared list under your lists and you can add places to it as usual.

I have no idea why Google does not provide feature parity between the mobile and web applications. -

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try creating a shared Google [My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/home) map.

Click "Share"

[image]

Then "Share on Drive"

[image]

Select "Anyone with the link" and change "Viewer" to "Editor"

[image]

The other users will need to be signed in to a Google account to edit.

Comment: Indeed, MyMaps is much more powerful, but sadly also much less integrated and streamlined across platforms

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the shared list is allowed, but removing an item that another user has added is not allowed.

To Add a location to the shared list:

First, ensure you have accepted the invitation to join the shared list.

Next, access the list with Google Maps.

Click the Add+ pin icon

Navigate to the location you want to add.

Choose Save to complete the add.

Comment: To remove a list item that someone else has added, send them an email or chat msg asking to remove it ;(

Answer (score 1):

This might be a late reply, but I had the same issue with my group of friends.
For some reason, sharing lists works better through the phone and not the PC.
To share a list with friends and allow them to edit, follow the following steps:

1. Go to Google Maps on your mobile phone app and open the List you want to share.
2. On the right hand corner of the screen, there should be 3 dots that opens different options, like 'Hide on your map', 'edit list' and 'sharing options.'
3. Click on 'Sharing Options.'
4. Change the 'List Type' to 'Shared.' After this, you should receive more options on the bottom of the page you are on.
5. On the 'Editing Options,' enable the 'Let others edit this list.'
6. Under 'List Editors,' you can now add your friends to edit the list by clicking on ' + Invite editors' and either manually add their email, phone number or name for them to edit (They need to have a google account), or you can click on 'copy to clipboard' and share a link with them via chat.
   From there, they need to open the link VIA PHONE (as for some reason it didn't work through PC for me) and click on 'Join.' They should be able to edit the list after this and you will all be able to see eachother's contributions.

Answer (score 0):

One detail, when adding someone as a 'List Editor' and clicking on '+ Invite editors', TEXTING the link was required, emailing it did not work.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is more of a comment than an Answer, so it's likely to be deleted or converted to a comment.